# Digital slew detection

Tags: filter-design

I'm looking for an algorithm to detect the slew rate of a 50Hz discrete input signal sampled at 400Hz. I'm doing the obvious - so a low-pass filter on *(sample - prev_sample) / deltaT* but this results in an oscillating output. I think this is because often the input is zero because *sample == prev_sample* and then you get this step input followed by zero again. What I need is a way of producing a smooth output that reacts quickly to large changes in input but doesn't ring when the input changes are small. I feel like I am missing some obvious reference here so if someone could set me straight that would be great!

Comment: This article by @RickLyons may be of interest: https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/814.php

Comment: @Andy Piper. I bet someone here can help you if you tell us more about your input signal. Saying your input signal is a "50 Hz signal" is too vague. Please tell us everything there is to know about your input signal. To quote Hannibal Lector, "What is it's nature?" (By the way, if I may be so bold, there should always be a space between the "50" and the "Hz" characters.)

Comment: Input signal is RC throttle updated at 50Hz, so can only move as fast as your fingers. Signal tends to either be lots of small adjustments or big swings up or down

Comment: @RichardLyons your article looks really interesting - I will try it and see whether it helps